# Oracle Database JDBC connection using datasource

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I am connecting to oracle database via datasource , as all know we have two types of connection one using sid and another using service name .
For Service name connection

```
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverType("thin");
        dataSource.setServerName(hostname);
        dataSource.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(port));
        dataSource.setServiceName(serviceName);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

This works perfectly fine but in this case if i want to establish a connection using sid There is no method called setSid() or anything like that Is there any way or should I use

```
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostname + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
      dataSource.setUrl(url);
      dataSource.setUser(username);
      dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

Is my approach correct or am i missing something
JDBC doc for reference https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html

Comment: Does it work? If so then you have answered your own question. If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: yes the way is proposed works fine i just wanted to see if there is a way not to code the url and make data source take care the work like it do in case of service name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the documentation, you would use `.setDatabaseName(sid)` but I don't have an Oracle database to test against.

```
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostname + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
      dataSource.setUrl(url);
      dataSource.setUser(username);
      dataSource.setPassword(password);
      dataSource.setDatabaseName(sid);
```

ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#setDatabaseName_java_lang_String_

> Set the name of a particular database on a server. In Oracle's jargon this is called SID (System Identifier).